# Can Deep Freeze destroy hard disks?

Tags: deep-freeze

I'm using Deep Freeze so that I could mess up with my computer. And just reboot then everything will be fine again. But recently my laptop hard disk failed(Its more than 2 years old).

I don't really have evidence if Deep Freeze has somehow contributed to the hastening of the disk failure.

I was just using it on one partition so that I could download and commit files on that partition.

While the default, if you have already tried it, protects 2 partitions.
Can you enlighten me on this one, because I really think that deep freeze is the one that cause the hdd failure. Is there any application that works like deep freeze which is more safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> because I really think that deep freeze is the one that cause the hdd failure.

Software can't create a mechanical failure in the hard disk. However, using something like DeepFreeze would increase the use of the drive to some extent and speed up the eventual failure of the disk (it wouldn't speed it up significantly though, if you used DeepFreeze for two weeks and your drive failed in the second week it was probably going to fail then anyway).

> Is there any application that works like deep freeze which is more safer.

Disk protection comes at the cost of extra disk reads and writes, which accelerate drive failure. If you want alternatives, try Windows SteadyState for Windows XP or Vista.